# How to set cookie SameSite=None instead of SameSite=LAX

Tags: cookie

In Magento 2, how do I set the cookie SameSite=None so that the server will not default to SameSite=LAX. For more info refer to the image below. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was due to Magento_AdminAnalytics module.
This module includes a js file in header section of all the pages i.e. //assets.adobedtm.com/a7d65461e54e/37baabec1b6e/launch-177bc126c8e6.min.js

through layout XML file

```
vendor/magento/module-admin-analytics/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml
```

here is the code:

```
<referenceContainer name="header">
            <block name="tracking" as="tracking" template="Magento_AdminAnalytics::tracking.phtml" ifconfig="admin/usage/enabled">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="tracking_url" xsi:type="string">//assets.adobedtm.com/a7d65461e54e/37baabec1b6e/launch-177bc126c8e6.min.js</argument>
                    <argument name="metadata" xsi:type="object">Magento\AdminAnalytics\ViewModel\Metadata</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Which is causing issue.

To resolve this, we have done below things:

1. Disable Magento_AdminAnalytics module using the below command:

   php bin/magento module:disable Magento_AdminAnalytics
2. Run following commands

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- php bin/magento cache:flush

3. Logout form admin and relogin Admin and check your customer grid and sales order grid, it should load now
4. If it still doesn't work then clear browser cache too!

***As an alternative for it, you can disable it from admin panel too***
Here are the steps:

```
A. Login to Admin Panel
B. Navigate to Stores > Configuration > ADVANCED > Admin
C. Scroll Down to Admin Usage
D. Set Enable Admin Usage Tracking to No
```

Here is screenshot of the setting:
[image]

Hope it should help you as well!